# How to set a margin for a html button background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have a bootstrap button with dimensions of `46 x 96px` and border radius of `22px`, when I hover this button I want to set the background color up to `40 x 90px`. (I do not want to fill the entire button)

I know this can be done using a `box-shadow` but I have different pages with different page colors where this button is used, so I do not want to change the box-shadow color page by page to match page's background color.

Any easy way to do this?

Comment: hello, please provide a descriptiv example so we can better understand what you want and check what you've already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage this with the `backgroud-clip` property.

> The background-clip CSS property sets whether an element's background extends underneath its border box, padding box, or content box.
>
> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

Make the size of your button 40px x 90px and add 3px of padding.

Then on hover, set `background-clip: content-box` and the background color will be restricted to just the content and not the padding.

Exaggerated example below:

```css
body {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
}

.button:hover {
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Button</div>
```

As you can see from the border the button size does not change but rather the background just does not extend to the border from the content.

Answer (score 0):

On hover, try adding a transparent border matching the button's background of size `6px`, and change the `background-color` as needed. This will give the intended effect, but will also visually reduce the size of the button. From your question it was not clear whether that was an acceptable side-effect.

Check out [this link](https://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/) to implement fully transparent borders.